# TLS HandShake on Windows 7 32 bit doesn't work with NET Framework 4 and 7

Tags: .net, https, windows-7, tls1.2, ssl-handshake

I'm trying to call a web service over HTTPS from a Windows 7 32bit system using a dot-net 4.6 and/or a self-contained single-file dot-net 7 application.
But I'm getting the following exceptions:

**INNEREXCEPTION**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
```

When i make the same call with Chrome on the same Windows 7 32bit system, the connection can be established.

**CHROME REQUEST**

```
CONNECT external-services.some.webservice.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: external-services.some.webservice.com:443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 02 72 BF 00 47 70 B8 00 33 24 A7 00 5E 21 B9 00 66 5D E5 DC BE 29 00 5E C9 00 00 14 22 00 44 34
"Time": 2000-03-03 09:04:18
SessionID: B0 CE 9D 00 35 5E 00 93 00 7A F0 00 95 00 00 64 C1 00 EF 1A 00 E0 DB CE F0 03 00 46 29 F4 3C 80
Extensions: 
       grease (0xaaaa)      empty
       server_name   external-services.some.webservice.com
       extended_master_secret      empty
       renegotiation_info   00
       supported_groups     grease [0xbaba], x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
       ec_point_formats     uncompressed [0x0]
       SessionTicket empty
       ALPN          h2, http/1.1
       status_request       OCSP - Implicit Responder
       signature_algs       ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512
       SignedCertTimestamp (RFC6962)      empty
       key_share     00 29 00 00 00 01 00 00 1D 00 20 00 A9 00 00 72 33 AE CE 00 BE D9 00 00 00 65 00 27 00 EB C6 00 00 E4 AF 00 86 B0 00 00 10 0F 00
       psk_key_exchange_modes      01 01
       supported_versions   grease [0xeaea], Tls1.3, Tls1.2, Tls1.1, Tls1.0
       0x001b        02 00 02
       0x4469        00 03 02 68 32
       grease (0xeaea)      00
       padding             168 null bytes
Ciphers: 
       [5A5A] Unrecognized cipher - See https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
       [1301] TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       [1302] TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       [1303] TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
       [C02B] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       [C02F] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       [C02C] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       [C030] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       [CCA9] TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
       [CCA8] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
       [C013] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       [C014] TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
       [009C] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
       [009D] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
       [002F] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
       [0035] TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
       [00]   NO_COMPRESSION
```

**CHROME RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 10:56:06.371
Connection: close
EndTime: 10:56:09.880
ClientToServerBytes: 1318
ServerToClientBytes: 2576

This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
To view the encrypted sessions inside this tunnel, enable the Tools > Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic option.

A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
SessionID:    64 00 00 1C D8 00 CB A1 8D 7A DC 00 00 DF B2 00 65 C9 CC 00 1B 33 60 5A 00 0C 6F 90 00 EF 82 F9
Random:             79 29 4E 00 A1 00 DE 00 CA 21 18 00 D5 00 00 C8 69 A3 C1 58 00 00 90 BF 9A 00 4D 44 11 E2 F4 86
Cipher:             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 [0xC02F]
CompressionSuite:    NO_COMPRESSION [0x00]
Extensions:
             renegotiation_info   00
             ALPN          h2
             ec_point_formats     uncompressed [0x0]
             extended_master_secret      empty
```

Using the dot-net applications, the HandShake (or something else) cannot be made.

**DOTNET REQUEST**

```
CONNECT external-services.some.webservice.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: external-services.some.webservice.com:443

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 65 00 7C 00 00 00 B9 63 00 50 BF 00 00 90 71 D1 00 39 00 D7 1B 00 BF 00 E5 BC 00 F6 00 00 71 C2
"Time": 2057-12-23 22:11:01
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name external-services.some.webservice.com
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  sha256_rsa, sha384_rsa, sha512_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha256_ecdsa, sha384_ecdsa, sha512_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha1_dsa
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009F]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009E]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [006A]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [0040]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

**DOTNET RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 11:11:01.868
Connection: close

fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to external-services.preprod.omni.pekao.com.pl (for #5) failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. < The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Win32 (SChannel) Native Error Code: 0x80090326
```

I can see, that Chrome was able to to talk with the endpoint using the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 Cipher, witch is missing in the dot-net connection.

Is there a way to configure dotnet 4.x or 7 to be able to make the call on a Windows 7 32bit system?

**my code**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // also tried 1.1 and 1.0

var requestContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Assets", "request.json"));

using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://external-services.some.webservice.com") })
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("User:Password");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("/api/calculators", UriKind.Relative), new StringContent(requestContent));
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Have yoo installed the latest updates and followed all the instructions to enable the correct cipher suites? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 You can use the free IIS Crypto tool to enabl cipher suites. Also install the latest updates for .NET Framework. I hope you are aware that Windows 7 is way out of date and has major security issues at this point.